# hyperref "steals" a line from the previous chapter with memoirs article option

Tags: hyperref, chapters, memoir, article

I'm starting to write a short report, so I would like chapters not taking up a page. Thus I'm using `memoir`'s `article` class option. I noticed that having `hyperref` enabled "steals" a line from the previous chapter.

Is there any way to make hyperref stop doing this? I really like having the links.

The following MWE:

```
\documentclass[article,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{test}
\section{quack}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{test}
\section{quack}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{test}
\section{quack}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Produces `hyperref`:

[image]

If `hyperref` is disabled the following is produced:

[image]

Comment: I don't get your output, but I get a page break between 3 and 3.1. I wonder what memoir is doing there.

Comment: your output indicates an older hyperref.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't get the page break you reported (I'm using texlive 2020).

Comment: @PeterWilson I do, and I also know why (we changed something in hyperref to resolve another bug, and now there are breakpoints after whatsits.) We will correct that in hyperref.

Comment: I note that with `hyperref` LaTeX reports that that it is redoing `nameref's sectioning` and `nameref's label`. Perhaps this has something to do with your problem. I'm not sure that `hyperref` works well with `memoir`s `article` option but I have no ideas about that.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer To me `hyperref` is very complicated. You are brave. Thank you.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Just checked: I'm using `memoir v3.7n`.

Comment: @PeterWilson the problem is not memoir, it is hyperref.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'll try updating tomorrow ;-) It still sounds off that the pagebreak should appear at a different location depending on whether `hyperref` is loaded though.

Comment: hyperref can change spacing and page breaking. It has to insert in various places code for the links and destinations. It tries hard to avoid side effects and in your case we can do it but not everywhere.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Fair, thanks for the help 8-}

Comment: @UlrikeFischer is this bug solved? Can we close this question as bug report and off topic?